# How to set dark ui theme in monodevelop > 4.0

Tags: linux, themes, monodevelop

I'm using unity 5.4 on linux and it comes with monodevelop 5.9.6. I want to change UI theme (not editor theme) to dark but there's no option like pointed out on

http://lebagage.free.fr/indexa527.html?Reminders:Development:Monodevelop_-_Change_to_dark_theme

There's no `Edit->Preferences->Visual Style->User Interface Theme`

Another approach is to change gtkrc. I found a gtkrc inside bin/ directory but replacing that with gtkrc on

https://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/200975-Turn-MonoDevelop-into-a-nice-Dark-Theme-IDE

doesn't make a change.

Any avaliable solution?

Comment: There is a Dark Theme available in 6.0+ if you can upgrade, see `Dark Theme and Visual Overhaul` @ https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using flatpak builds, there is a new version ([6.1.1.15-2](https://download.mono-project.com/monodevelop/monodevelop-6.1.1.15-2.flatpak)) which includes a dark theme:
[image: Flatpak]

Commit: [Add a module for Dark theme](https://github.com/directhex/monodevelop-flatpak/commit/f0555f176ee817a9b9f48a38ff2eea43565a8673).

Answer (score 1):

Go into tools->options->syntax highlighting. Weird place for it to be, I know.